# How to split a string after 2nd occurrence of dot(.) in java

Tags: java, string

I have a string which looks something like this(the most basic form):

`String str = "1.0.0.190"`

The str can be something like this as well:

`1.11.0.12 or 2.111.1.190 or 1.0.0.0`

I want to split the string at the 2nd occurrence of the dot(.). How can I achieve that ?

**Output:**

```
String str = "1.0.0.190" 
String output = "1.0"
```

Comment: Can't you just split the string on all occurrences of dots and then just take the first two elements and join them?

String string ="1.0.0.190";
String[] parts = string.split(".");
parts = parts[0] + "." + parts[1];

Comment: 1) find the position of the second dot; 2) spit at this position.

Comment: or split on all dots and take whatever elements you want

Comment: try may this can help not tested yet: str .substring(0,str .indexOf('.', 1 + str .indexOf('.')))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd fit the answer to OP's level, so I wouldn't recommend split or regexps to him...

If you need substring to second dot, simply find second dot and cut the string to that position...

```
public class DotSubstring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "1.2.3.4";
        int secondDotPosition = findSecondDotPosition(s);
        if (secondDotPosition > 0) {
            System.out.println(s.substring(0, secondDotPosition));
        } else {
            System.out.printf("ERROR: there is not a 2nd dot in '%s'%n", s);
        }
    }

    private static int findSecondDotPosition(String s) {
        int result = -1;
        int dotsToFind = 2;
        char[] ca = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < ca.length; ++i) {
            if (ca[i] == '.') --dotsToFind;
            if (dotsToFind == 0) return i;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

The problem with split for beginner is, that is accepts regexp, that's why it is escaped in Joop Eggen's answe like this `str.split("\\.")`.

And yes, that can be achieved in one line as user3458271 wrote in a comment same as xyz later in answer, just error checking would be more difficult (for example if there are no 2 dots...).

Answer (score 5):

In one line with substring and indexOf:

```
String output = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(".",str.indexOf(".")+1));
```

Answer (score 1):

For the other fields too:

```
String[] halfs = str.split("\\.");
String[] fulls = new String[halfs.length / 2];
for (int i = 0; i < fulls.length; ++i) {
    fulls[i] = halfs[2*i] + "." + halfs[2*i + 1];
}
return fulls[0];
```

The same technique reduced for the first field:

```
String[] halfs = str.split("\\.", 3);
return halfs[0] + "." + halfs[1];
```

Simply:

```
return str.replaceAll("^([^.]*\\.[^.]*)\\..*$", "$1");
```

Comment: Why so complex? Your first code for `"1.2.3.4.5"` returns `{ "1.2", "3.4"}`, also from maintenance point of view I wouldn't call the replace solution simple, just because it's one-liner...

Comment: @Betlista as the OP did not provide code for something quite elementary, I wanted to show a couple of swiss knifes: `split` and `replaceAll`. I was interrupted by my work, so "Simply" was all I wrote. By the way xyz has a nice answer, though having only `indexOf` as "hammer" would make many parsing problems ugly.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "2.111.1.190";
    String[] out = input.split("\\.");

    String output1 = out[0]+"."+out[1];
    System.out.println(output1);

    String output2 = "";
    for(int x=2; x < out.length; x++)
        output2 += out[x] +".";

    System.out.println(output2);
}
```